# Profile specific properties not being passed to module

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have several `profile`s defined in my parent `pom` and would like to have properties defined for each module. Here is my profile section looks like:

```
<profile>
    <id>profile1</id>
    <properties>
        <prop1>val1.1</prop1>
        <prop2>val1.2</prop2>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>warmodule1</module>
        <module>warmodule2</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>profile2</id>
    <properties>
        <prop1>val2.1</prop1>
        <prop2>val2.2</prop2>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>warmodule3</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

I run `mvn package -P profile1` to build warmodule1 and warmodule1 with prop1 and prop2 of values val1.1 and val1.2 respectively and `mvn package -P profile2` to build warmodule3 with prop1 and prop2 of values val2.2 and val2.2 respectively.

It works for profile2 but in profile1, the properties are passed only to the first module listed (warmodule1) while warmodule1 gets empty strings.

When I run each module individually and pass the properties from the command line (e.g. `mvn clean package -Dprop1=val1.1 -Dprop2-val1.2`) it works fine, just not when I set the properties inside profile definition in the parent pom and run the parent build.

**How can I effect both modules in the first profile with profile specific properties and not just the first one listed?**

Comment: It shouldn't affect just the first module. Can you make a simple [mcve]? How did you determine it didn't affect the second module?

Comment: because some string replacements in the second module took empty strings rather than the property values set

Comment: got it figured out.  the reason was something else.  please see my answer below.

Comment: Never defined [modules in profiles](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

The properties were not being passed from the parent `pom` to warmodule2 because warmodule2, unlike warmodule1, did not have a parent defined:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroupd</groupId>
        <artifactId>parentArtifactID</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

When I added it to warmodule2`s pom, the parameters were passed successfully.

As a side note, I didn't write these poms to begin with, so it was someone else's omission that the second module didn't have a parent declared.